# Show that all groups of order 48 are solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I find that there are either $1$ or $3$ Sylow-$2$ subgroups, and $1, 4$ or $16$ Sylow-$3$ subgroups. I need one of them to be $1$, so that it is normal, so I can mod out by it and have $2$ $p$-groups $N$, $G/N$, which are thus both solvable which implies that $G$ is solvable.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If $G$ has $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, then $G$ acts non-trivially on them by conjugation, therefore there is a non-trivial mapping $f:G\to S_3$. Then $|G/\ker f|=2,3,6$.  This action is transitive, so $|G/\ker f|=3,6$ and  $|\ker f|=16,8$ and both these groups are solvable.

Comment: $f$ is surjective group hom. so how is $G/Kerf = 2,3$? Isn't $G/Kerf$ supposed to be isomorphic to $S_{3}$ which implies its order to be $6$?

Comment: I added the answer.

Comment: Why can you not get $|G/\rm{ker}(f)| = 6$?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft Oh, thank you!

Comment: @sergey You are right, I corrected.

Comment: @sergey Why would $f$ necessarily be surjective?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft just by what f is doing, its mapping $g$ to $\epsilon_{g}$ where, the former is a permutation of 3 elements representing the three 2-Sylows in the orbit

Comment: @sergey that does not make it surjective.

Comment: @BorisNovikov I guess my confusion is in the fact that, i don't understand where the numbers 2 and 3 came from for the order of $G/Kerf.$ And besides that if you are showing that $G/Kerf$ and $Kerf$ are solvable, then where is the contradiction?

Comment: @sergey He had just forgotten to mention the possibility of the order being $6$. There is no contradiction. He is providing a normal solvable subgroup with solvable quotient.

Comment: interesting, i guess i was just expecting the only possibility to be 1 2-Sylow so we could mod out by it and have the subgroups be 2-Sylow, G/2-Sylow

Comment: @sergey I was out of Internet several hours. Did Tobias Kildetoft answer on your additional questions?