# prove that $GL_2(\Bbb Z_3)$ is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

I need to prove that $GL_2(\Bbb Z_3)$ is solvable

What I tried:

I know that $GL_2(\Bbb Z_3)$ has $(3^2-1)(3^2-3) = 48 = 3 * 2^4$ elements.

I know that $n_3 \in \{1,4,16\}$ and $n_2 \in \{1,3\}$

here I'm stuck ....  any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Burnsides theorem ?

Comment: not allowed to use it :/

Comment: There is an element of order $2$ in its center. Can you see it? You might proceed from there.

Comment: Another hint: how many one-dimensional subspaces does a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ have?

Comment: about the center - how do i know what it is? there are 2 one dimensional subspaces ? (1) and (2)? how does it help?

Comment: An almost duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547693/show-that-all-groups-of-order-48-are-solvable

Comment: As for the center, in the group of invertible matrices, there are some matrices which obviously commute with all others. No, there are not 2 one-dimensional subspaces, there are more than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $H=SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$, the subgroup of matrices with determinant $1$. Show that $|H|=24$ and is normal subgroup. Then you may try to proceed that $H$ is solvable (and since $G/H$ is also solvable, so is $G$.)

One reason to proceed this way is that, as you were considering number of Sylow subgroups, it is better to work for it in $H$ rather than in $G$; in $G$ no Sylow subgroups are normal. But, in $H$, some Sylow subgroup is normal. It requires some detailed computations.

Comment: so for $SL_2(Z_3)$ I can show that $n_3 \in \{1,4\}$ and $n_2 \in \{1,3\}$ how do i show one of them is normal? thanks

Comment: **(1)** In $SL_2(Z_3)$, consider all matrices of form $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$; do they form subgroup? What is its order?  **(2)** Consider matrices $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ * & 1\end{bmatrix}$; what they form? **(3)** From (1) and (2), you can conclude about number of some Sylow subgroups. **(4)** Consider element $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ in $SL_2(Z_3)$; it is in center of group; its order is $2$. **(5)** So multiply this element to elements of Sylow $3$ subgroup to obtain cyclic group of order $6$. How many cyclic groups of order $6$ will be there?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution following the hint of @Geoff Robinson in the comments.

In a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Z_3$ there are $3^2-1$ non-zero elements, and since every one-dimensional subspace is determined by $3-1$ elements, the set $A$ of one-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb Z_3^2$ has $\frac{3^2-1}{3-1} = 4$ elements. Now there is a group action of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_3)$ on $A$ given by left translation. This extends to a group homomorphism $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_3)\to S_4$. In particular, the kernel of this group homomorphism is $Z = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}\mid 0\neq a\in\mathbb Z_3\right\}$ because the image lands in the same equivalence class. By a cardinality argument, we know this homomorphism is a surjection, and we know both $Z$ and $S_4\cong \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_3)/Z$ are solvable, therefore $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_3)$ is solvable as well.